# how can I return array from function in java and retrieve value at the time of calling?

Tags: java, arrays, apache-poi

I want to make a function which returns an array. this function get the value from the excel sheet and store the value in array. this function return a 2-D array when we call it. when we call this function it works fine.
Now I want the value of return array is store into other 2-d array at the time of calling.

```
 public String[][] GetValue(String Pathfile, String sheetName, int startrow) throws IOException{
        File excel= new File(Pathfile);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
          XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
          int colNum = ws.getRow(startrow).getLastCellNum();
          String [][] arrays = new String [1][colNum];
          for(int i=0;i<=colNum;i++){
                  XSSFRow row= ws.getRow(startrow);
                  XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i);
                  arrays[0][i] = cellToString(cell);
                  System.out.println(arrays[0][i]);
          }
          return arrays;
      }
```

My calling function code is here - I made a `String[][]` data and put the value by calling function- but data array didnot get value from calling function.

```
 String[][] data = GetValue("./src/dataexcel.xlsx","Orgdata",2);
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        // System.out.println(data.length);
        String baseUrl = data[0][1];
        System.out.println(baseUrl);
        String Fullname = data[0][2];
        String Email= data[0][3];
        String Password=data[0][4];
        String Orgname=data[0][5];
    }
```

Comment: What problem you are facing? Explain in detail about problem.

Comment: Looks like you do not need 2-d array. Use 1-d array instead.

Comment: I think OP want such kind of construct like this: `returningArrrayMethod()[0]`

Comment: How can i display return arrays.....or ......store value of retrun array in other 2-d arrays...

Comment: Plz help ....to solve this issue..............